# How would you do that with Eloquent - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have this logic in a controller :

```
// hydratation part 1 (cf son modele) 
    $matiere->fill($request->all());
    
// hydratation part 2 with attributes not in the POST
    $matiere->id_ecole = Session::get('id_ecole');
    $request->has('matiere_inactive') ? $matiere->matiere_inactive = '1' : $matiere->matiere_inactive = null;
    if ($matiere->exists) {
        $matiere->auteur_modif = Session::get('nom').' '.Session::get('prenom');
    } else {
        $matiere->auteur_creation = Session::get('nom').' '.Session::get('prenom');
    }
```

I think that the part 2 could be present in the model , instead of the controller (I like to have 'brief' controller).

Is it a good idea ?

If yes how could I do that ?

My model is :

```
class Matiere extends Model {

    protected $table = 'matiere';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_matiere';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_matiere',
        'code_court_matiere',
        'libelle_matiere'
    ];
    
    public function setCodeCourtMatiereAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['code_court_matiere'] = strtoupper($value);
    }

    public function setLibelleMatiereAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['libelle_matiere'] = ucwords($value);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Laravel 5. 3

you can do that by creating a method on Matiere model.

```
Here is a simple example: 

ExampleController.php

$mat = new \App\Matiere();

$feedback = $mat->addm($request);



Matiere.php

public function addm($request)
{
    $this->id_ecole = \Session::get('id_ecole');
    $request->has('matiere_inactive') ? $this->matiere_inactive = '1' : $this->matiere_inactive = null;

    $this->save();

    return $this->id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this idea, i will work on it. But is it a good idea to use Session directly into the model ?